# Invisible places mentioned in stories?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana

Are there any invisible places exsist on earth which are not accessible to general humans but restricted or visible  only to few who have the authority to enter into.

If yes are such places mentioned in our Stories? Can we find details about such places?

Thank you.

Comment: Gyanganj is considered invisible place on earth. Besides Gyanganj, there are a ton of other places which are although not invisible but not accessible to general public. Many of such places are located near Mount Kailash.

Answer (score 2):

It is believed that such places exist in different dimension and plane. Somewhat between physical and astral. This is referred to as Shambhala in buddhist texts, Siddhashrama and gjnana ganja in hindu scriptures and stories.

This is a fascinating subject and I recommend you to read books like [Gyan-ganj](https://www.scribd.com/document/205313536/Gyanganja-M-M-Gopinath-Kaviraj) and [Search of Secret India](http://www.courtofrecord.org/archive/Paul-Brunton-A-Search-in-Secret-India.pdf).

> The Gyanganj (Jnanganj) Yogashram – the ancient name of this Yogashram
>   was ‘Indra Bhawan’. This ancient Ashram was renovated and restored to
>   its pristine glory again by Swami Gyananand Paramahans, a disciple of
>   Maharshi Mahatapa. Under his able administration and responsible
>   management it started functioning properly once again under the new
>   name Gyanganj.
>
> Gyanganj is an extraordinary spiritual training centre. The
>   Brahmacharis, Brahmacharinis and Paramahansas of this centre, after
>   getting established in the state Aham-Brahmasmi, roam about in the
>   universe as, when and where they like.
>
> The Gyanganj (Jnanganj) Yogashram with a perimeter of about 16
>   kilometres, is situated in the western region of Tibet, an upland in
>   the Himalayas to the north of India. This ancient Ashram was renovated
>   and restored to its pristine glory once again by Swami Gyananand
>   Paramhans, a disciple of Maharshi Mahatapa. Under his able
>   administration and responsible management it started functioning
>   properly once again under the new name of Gyanganj. All this
>   renovation took place about seven hundred years earlier, i.e., say
>   about 1225 A.D. Yogiraj Shri Vishuddhanand had eulogised about the
>   eminence of Gyanganj Yogashram in brief at times about the
>   supernatural experiences and powers of the Yogis of this Ashram.
>
> About the name ‘Gyanganj’
>
> Now ‘Gyan’ is a Sanskrit word and ‘Gan’j appears to be a Persian word.
>   How come that the words of these two different languages have been
>   joined up to form the word Gyan-ganj? In actual fact Ganj is a word,
>   the root of which is Sanskrit and it travelled from Bharat (India) to
>   Persia: Ganj : Gaji (Bhwadi ganiya Dhatu) + Yan (Pratyaya) The word
>   ‘Ganj’ means ‘Treasury of Jewels’ so ‘Gyanganj’ literally means
>   ‘Treasury of Knowledge of All Kinds’.

Paramhansa Vishuddhanand Ji Gandh-baba

> Shri Vishuddhananda’s childhood name was Bholanath Chattopadhyaya.
>   Siddha Yogi Swami Nimanand Paramahansa of the secret Gyanganj
>   Yogashram in Tibet took Bholnath to Gyanganj ashram. Yogiraj
>   Vishuddhanand Paramhansadeva was the first Yogi-Saint to introduce and
>   propagate Surya-Vijnan, solar science, into the world for the first
>   time. Up till then this science was confined to the precints of the
>   ancient secrets of Yogashram at Gyanganj in the Himalayas in Tibet and
>   was known only to the ancients. Baba stayed in Gyanganj Ashram for 12
>   years. Surya i.e., Sun or Savita means ‘source of creation’. According
>   to Surya-Vijnan there are 360 rays of the sun which go to form the
>   whole creation of the Universe. Baba converted cotton wool, flowers
>   and leaves into stones, wood, etc. by the incidence of appropriate
>   rays of the Sun. He demonstrated practically how minute particles of
>   ingredients of various objects could be dispersed or assembled and
>   destroyed or created through the proces of Surya-Vijnan. As a result
>   of his adherence to the strict rules of the Brahmacharya period,
>   Bholanath had freed himself from the influence of ego and had also
>   developed the spirit of surrender to the will of the Supreme Power.

[Source](http://www.shivayoga.net/gyanganj-2/gyanganj-jnanganj-yogashram-in-tibet/)

Comment: "such places exist in different dimension and plane" - how is this different from an imaginary place that simply doesn't exist?

Comment: @sv. from people like paul brunton and vishuddhananda we come to know that people have lived there and come back to normal world. 
it has access to very limited people.

Comment: @sv. Vishuddhananda demonstrated such things in front of westerners too.. like materializing some objects with the help of special lens and focusing suns rays and transforming objects. etc

Comment: I'm a little wary of anecdotal evidences. FYI, my earlier comment was based on [The Parable of the Invisible Gardener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Invisible_Gardener).

Comment: @sv, you are saying "Prove to me that a mango is sweet. I will not eat it. I will only look at it and touch it". Your ability to accept proof is limited to 5 senses. If you want to verify for yourself that people in other dimensions exist, you have to be willing to 'taste' the mango. One simple (but hard) way - Speak truth for 12 years. At the end of it, you will be able to meet them if you simply say so. There are other ways too. But if you are not willing to do any of them, I'll ask *you* a question - "how is this different from wanting to taste a mango without tasting it"

Comment: @sv. yes scientific published evidences are not there. I didnt claim also.

Comment: @ram "Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence." It's easy to prove a mango is sweet with a real mango. If you can't find a mango, maybe another sweet tasting fruit will do. Claims such as "places exist in different dimension and plane...somewhat between physical and astral" need extraordinary proof. Mere statements by some gurus and their disciples cannot be sold as proof.

Comment: @sv, "It's easy to prove a mango is sweet with a real mango" - not if you refuse to taste it. "If you can't find a mango, maybe another sweet tasting fruit will do" - no it won't. you need to prove that a mango is sweet, not a banana. just as the act of tasting a mango is necessary pre-requisite to realize it is sweet, the act of penance is necessary pre-requisite to realize people of different dimensions exist. if I refuse to taste a mango, and go on rambling that none can prove it is sweet, i am not fit for scientific discussion.